# Should I disable bitmapscan on PostgreSQL when using SSD?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was reading the
https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys
when I came across these lines:

> The PostgreSQL database uses two operations in this case: a Bitmap Index Scan followed by a Bitmap Heap Scan. They roughly correspond to Oracle's INDEX RANGE SCAN and TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID with one important difference: it first fetches all results from the index (Bitmap Index Scan), then sorts the rows according to the physical storage location of the rows in the heap table and than fetches all rows from the table (Bitmap Heap Scan). This method reduces the number of random access IOs on the table.

It occurred to me that this makes no sense when we are using Postgres on SSD.  The calculation of sorting storage location may be a waste. Because SSDs are random-access only devices (if I didn’t get it wrong.)

And I did some test also, by turning on/off the `enable_bitmapscan`

```
set enable_bitmapscan to on;
explain analyse select count(distinct myid) from experiment.mytable where name='my_name';
----
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=63196.06..63196.07 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=668.845..668.846 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mytable  (cost=696.41..63110.95 rows=34045 width=82) (actual time=54.967..216.382 rows=178705 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (name = 'my_name'::text)
        Heap Blocks: exact=164942
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mytable_name_visittime_idx  (cost=0.00..687.89 rows=34045 width=0) (actual time=28.365..28.365 rows=178705 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (name = 'my_name'::text)
Planning time: 1.411 ms
Execution time: 669.576 ms



set enable_bitmapscan to off;
explain analyse select count(distinct myid) from experiment.mytable where name='my_name';
----
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=68369.46..68369.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=585.496..585.497 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using mytable_name_visittime_idx on mytable  (cost=0.56..68284.34 rows=34045 width=82) (actual time=0.019..126.553 rows=178705 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (name = 'my_name'::text)
Planning time: 0.062 ms
Execution time: 585.542 ms
```

There is indeed a noticeable improvement
When enable_bitmapscan the planner use the BitmapHeapScan + BitmapIndexScan. When disable it the planner choose the IndexScan only.

Comment: Indeed SSDs have very low seek time - so it is worth to disable optimizations which are designed for spinning disks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also tune the config to let PostgreSQL decide whether random IO cost will be more than the sequential cost.

Change [this setting - random_page_cost](https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/random_page_cost/) in `postgresql.conf` to 1.0, which is equivalent to `seq_page_cost`.

This will tell PostgreSQL that the cost of random IO is equivalent to the cost of sequential IO.